# How to export assets from an .SWF container?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Given is an online swf on Hubworld's site, which loads two configuration XMLs into an .swf file, then displays a game. A copy of the Flash with the two configuration files can be found here. (http://db.tt/zYT9Owg5). If unzipped into a folder, it loads the two XML files and displays everything correctly. The problem is, how to take it apart?

I tried decompiling the file, but it only shows up as a (mostly) empty file with a single symbol and a few misc tags inside it, despite the file itself containing several hundreds of vectors. (http://i.imgur.com/si6gq.png). I severly doubt that any sort of encryption or obfuscation is present, since it's a children's game and I took apart many others without a problem. How could I retrieve the said files from the container?

Comment: Mind you, I'm not looking to access the code itself, but assets from a flash file. Vectors and images. I don't believe accessing something publicly viewable and downloadable on the internet would count as a crime or worthy of downvoting. I simply look to access the said graphic files, not use or make a profit from them.

Comment: appropriating visual assets or code without the owner's consent, even for non-profit use, is illegal.

Comment: you should look in the forums first before posting questions that have been already answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swf contains another swf embedded as a ByteArray.  I'm not sure why, but this is probably an obfuscation technique.

You can view the actual assets by running the swf in [SWFWire Debugger](http://www.swfwire.com/debugger).  This application will dump the swf that is loaded from the ByteArray into the same folder as fashion.swf.  You can then load this in your decompiler, or [SWFWire Inspector](http://www.swfwire.com/inspector) if you just want to view the assets.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sean, that was a lifesaver. Ran it through the debugger and the assets did in fact show up. Just for future clarification, I was not looking to use any of the assets for illegal purposes or to gain profit - I was simply looking to take apart the structure of the file. Thanks again man.

Comment: If the program was meant to be taken apart, the code would be open-source and freely available. The only time you should be using a decompiler is on your **own** project, such as if you accidentally lost the source to your project.